# Ubuntu Server 14.04 with Cups LPD/LPR support

Tags: server, 14.04, printing, lpd

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Lamp, Samba and Cups installed by server media installation. I would like to also set this up as a print server with cups and `lpd`/`lpr` support.

I have a similar setup in RHEL 4. In RHEL, it uses `cups-lpd` and the service `inetd`; but I don't know what packages to use in Ubuntu.

There's `xinetd` for Ubuntu but I saw somewhere that `inetd(bsd)` works better than `xinetd`. And what packages would I use in place of cups-lpd?

Is there someone who can provide a step-to-step way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found an [answer here](http://www.errr-online.com/index.php/2010/09/21/ubuntu-linux-cups-server-with-legeacy-lpd-support-using-cups-lpd/)

Essentially it required these steps on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine:

```
sudo apt-get install openbsd-inetd
```

Add a line to `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
printer stream tcp nowait lp /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-lpd cups-lpd
```

Restart inetd with:

```
/etc/init.d/openbsd-inetd restart
```

I'm still trying to configure the `lpd` setup, but because you already had a usable configuration, this should at least get you past that point.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Do not use to install the package contained into media cd/dvd automatcaly. Prefer to install a minimal server and download the packages by apt, cos it will not make problems with avahi daemon. Thats the key!